# Magento 1 to Magento 2 models Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api') and Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')

Tags: magento2, model, shipment, conversion

I have to convert (translate) these two models from Magento 1 to Magento 2:
`Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')` and `Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')`
Where are they, and how can I get them using object manager? I need to access these methods(their substitutes) in Magento 2:

```
Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->create($a, $b, 'shipment', false, 1);
Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->addTrack($a, 'custom', $b, $c);
Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId);
```

Comment: Which function u want to use for both of them?

Comment: Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->create($a, $b, 'shipment', false, 1);
Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->addTrack($a, 'custom', $b, $c);
Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId);

Comment: $shipment = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment')->load($shipmentId); for load shipment id

Answer (score 1):

[1]

```
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); //instance of\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager
$shipment   = $_objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface');
$shipment->addTrack();
```

Reference file **magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\ShipmentFactory.php**

[2]

```
$shipment = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shi‌​pment')->load($shipm‌​entId);
```

Comment: The $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shi‌​pment') method is used to create the factory object, but it is not the same ->create method to create the shipment as in Magento 1:
Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->create